# Text offsets by 1px on hover with color transition

Tags: html, css, webkit

On [this](http://novaember.com/discussions/1) webpage, when you hover the ratings on the right side of each post, the icon will offset 1px to the left while the color is transitioning. However, this only occurs in Chrome, and perhaps Safari, but not in Firefox.

Is this a bug? Is there something wrong with my code?

The icon itself is from a font, FontAwesome.
When I tried to recreate this part of the page in a jsfiddle, the bug did not occur.

This is what I see:

[image: Animation]

Comment: Your link to the website does not show the icons or the area of interest.  Can you adjust the demo page?

Comment: Oh, there's a bug in my code for unregistered users - fixing..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do see the issue in Chrome, but not in Firefox.  I was able to fix the problem by making a minor adjustment to one of your CSS rules:

```
.post-ratings-rating {
    ...
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    width: 30px;
    ...
}
```

If you change the `width` to an absolute value using pixels, icons don't shift.  The relative unit was the source of the problem.  Why? I suspect the browsers do their arithmetic differently when converting from em's to px's.

Comment: Great! and the trick works in Firefox, so you are good to carry on!